# website has a bug

Tags: wp-debug

Wordpress website Red Bug shown in top line, I have an error message:

```
NOTICE: wp-includes/functions.php:5313 - WP_Scripts::localize was called incorrectly. The $l10n parameter must be an array. To pass arbitrary data to scripts, use the wp_add_inline_script() function instead. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 5.7.0.)
require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/twentyseventeen/index.php'), get_header, locate_template, load_template, require_once('/themes/twentyseventeen/header.php'), wp_head, do_action('wp_head'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wp_enqueue_scripts, do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, ClefUserSettings->register_assets, wp_localize_script, WP_Scripts->localize, _doing_it_wrong, trigger_error.
```

I tried to deactivate plugins for trouble shooting mode when having website page problems, not showing or contact forms not working. I think it was then the debug message appeared.I deactivated my SSL Cert my mistakae as well, though TSOhost say there's problem with it at their end. I'm a novice at website creation. Getting alot of problems with WPress theme Twenyseventeen. Is there someting I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress function `wp_localize_script()` is used for making translated strings available to the Javascript side of things.

The notice you are seeing is due to one of your plugins using `wp_localize_script()`, and passing in a non-array as the third parameter.

Are you using a "single sign on" plugin? If so, see if temporarily disabling this makes the notice go away. If so, that is the source of the issue.

Comment: I have Query Monitor installed as a plug-in, is that just showing the problem rather than helping with it?

Comment: Hi I've now sorted out the problems thanks